# Rollback a build using AWS CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline

What is the best mechanism to implement to rollback a deployment that is orchestrated using CodePipeline? The source comes from a S3 bucket and we are looking to see if there is a one-lick rollback mechanism without manual intervention.

Answer (score 4):

CodePipeline doesn't support rollback currently. If you are using CodeDeploy as the deployment action, you can setup rollback on alarm or failed deployment on the CodeDeploy DeploymentGroup. The cloud formation template to enable auto-rollback for a CodeDeploy deployment group looks like:

```
Type: "AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup"
Properties:
  ...
  AutoRollbackConfiguration: 
    Enabled: true
    Events: 
      - "DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE"
      - "DEPLOYMENT_STOP_ON_ALARM"
  AlarmConfiguration:
    Alarms:
      - CloudWatchAlarm1
      - CloudWatchAlarm2
    Enabled: true
```

You can find more information about it at [Deployments and Redeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-rollback-and-redeploy.html)

Comment: What if CodeDeploy is not used? Deployment system without Rollback functionality is the nonsence....

Comment: Seems like CodeDeploy just redeploys a previous version as a new one. Should be possible to emulate this with CodePipeline and a Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

In case we are not using AWS CodeDeploy, then anyday we can use the manual way of rollback, which is to redeploy the previous stable build or tag.

Comment: How would you go about doing that?